# How to install Git on Linux

Tags: linux, git, installation

I'm trying to install Git with `apt-get`:

```
$ apt-get install git-core
```

I get this error:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13 Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I'm pretty sure that my account is the root, but I tried doing this anyway:

```
$ su -
```

After which I get a response:

```
su: must be run from a terminal
```

Also, running sudo tells me the program isn't installed. I also can't install it because of the above error (must be run from a terminal).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: it appears your problem is mainly that you are not root, and you are not on a terminal. How are you connecting to the server/box/whatever ?

Comment: With SSH version 2. I'm using a software similar to Putty.

Comment: Is the machine from your hosting provider or do you (your company) own it? Are you even supposed to have root privileges?

Comment: I've sent a ticket about this. Awaiting response. It's a hosting provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core
```

Comment: I get "-bash: sudo: command not found"

Comment: What distribution are you running?

Comment: Running uname -a yields this following;

Linux p9.runhosting.com 2.6.32.32nopreempt #5 SMP Tue Aug 2 14:01:50 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I think my account is the root because it's the only account I have on the server (I might be wrong). Is there a way to find out if my account is the root? It's the same account I'm using to login to the administration panel of the server.

Comment: If you are root your prompt typically will have a `#` character instead of `$`...

Comment: It appears I'm not root then. But I can't run su nor sudo (I listed the  errors above).

Comment: If this is a hosted solution, do you even have root permission on the box? Maybe it is locked down?

Comment: Do not type "su -", just "su"

Comment: the command 'id' will tell you which user you are, root has a numeric id of 0

Comment: "id" yields this: uid=1000098(1000098) gid=3000 groups=3000. I might lack root permissions on the box, I'm trying to find out where to check that now and how to change it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a working C compiler on some computer, have experience with compilation (`make configure && configure && make all && make install`) and have perl and curl/openssl development files (headers and libraries), you can compile Git yourself and configure it to be installed in your home directory on that system. It is very easy and was actually a recommended installation routine in early days of Git development (the Makefile still has `$HOME` as default installation directory).

After installation you can collect the files and copy it to your remote system.

You can always find snapshots (.tar.gz) of current release/stable branch on [kernel.org](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=snapshot;h=HEAD;sf=tgz). Just unpack it somewhere and run the commands above. If you need offline documentation (manpages or html files), you'll need asciidoc installed on the development machine.

Comment: configure never works. It used to with older versions. All you need now is the make script. Run once to compile, then again to install.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk: you're wrong. While seldom needed, it does work.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then. Every time I checkout a tag in the git repo, the configure file is missing.

Comment: Ah, I see. I failed to mention this: `make configure`. It is on the first page in the file INSTALL. Answer updated.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk: Apologies, indeed. I seldom use the routine: all my machines are a very standard Debian, which compile out of the box.