# Can I install git on a shared hosting server?

Tags: linux, git, installation

My previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550029/how-to-install-git-on-linux/11550038#11550038) led me to this one - is it possible to install and use git on a shared hosting server (if it's not provided by default) where using apt-get isn't possible?

I've sent a ticket concerning this issue (apt-get not working), and got this response;

> This is a shared hosting account and your user is not able to modify
>   or install/uninstall new software on the server.
>
> This functionality is only available on our VPS hosting solutions. For
>   more information please refer to the following link:
>   http://landahost.runhosting.de/vps-hosting.html

Since I only need git, is there a way "around" this issue?

Comment: Appropriate binaries can be copied over manually (or perhaps built locally). However, be sure this is not again the TOS. The "workabout" is thus to not use administrative-level tools.

Comment: Sounds like you have your answer already from your provider.

Comment: Install git on your workstation, "publish" to a local directory, then upload that.  Or, if that doesn't meet your needs, **describe your needs** and somebody may try to help.

Comment: Since svn is supported, I guess the only thing I can do is work on a svn repository and then migrate it to git.

Comment: @Tool Or use a *real* host, such as GitHub.

Comment: compile it from source (assuming they haven't locked down gcc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to compile git and move it over to the server. This stackoverflow Q&A does a pretty good job answering your question: [Compile git for 32-bit linux on shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147730/compile-git-for-32-bit-linux-on-shared-hosting)

Good luck. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with a couple of clients, and I ended up writing a small python script with a php helper to workaround that.

It's not perfect but beats having to deal with uploading / checking files by hand.

check my [dvcs-helper](https://github.com/OneOfOne/dvcs-helper).